# Looker Studio - How to create a pie chart representing multiple data columns?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to create a pie chart showing, of the total # of attempts, how many were successful, and how many failed. the data looks roughly like this...

```
| date     | attempts || success  |  fail    |
| -------- | -------- || -------- |--------  |
| 1/1/24   | 100      || 90       | 10       |
| 1/2/24   | 50       || 45       | 5        |
```

when I attempt to make the chart, it only gives me one column of data and each slice is a date.